# Create temporary attribute for Rails object and pass to View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Exam model, which has a database attribute `score`. Now, I want to have another attribute named `rating`, which converts this score to rating (A, B, C, D, F). I don't want to create another column for `rating`, so I used virtual attribute as follow:

```
  class Exam < ActiveRecord::Base
     attr_accessor :rating
     after_initialize :set_rating
     after_find :set_rating

     private
     def set_rating
        self.rating = case score
          when 0..49 then "F"
          when 50..79 then "B"
          else "A" 
     end
 end
```

This works, in the sense that I can call

```
e = Exam.find_by_student("John")
e.rating
```

However, the object `e` does not have attribute rating attached to it. So if I pass object `e` to Rails view, I can't get `e.rating` where rating is an attribute.

How can I achieve what I would like, i.e., a database-less attribute that is available after_find?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scrap all that and just define a method called `rating`.

```
class Exam < ActiveRecord::Base

  # ...

  def rating
    case score
      when 0..49 then "F"
      when 50..79 then "B"
      else "A" 
    end
  end

end
```

If you need to include this "attribute" in a JSON response, you can pass the `:methods` parameter to [`as_json`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON/as_json) to explictly include it:

```
render json: @exam.as_json(members: :rating)
```

Comment: Problem is when I pass object Exam to `View`, I no longer have this method `rating` available. So your solution won't work for my case.

Comment: Um. I can guarantee that you *do* have the method, and that this solution *will* work for your case. Any methods you define on your class *will* be available in the view. Are you defining the method as `private`? There's no reason to do so and that *would* make it appear to not respond to `rating`.

Comment: And I would create a new RatingClass, to keep the model clean.
Read more here, with the RatingExample: http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/

Comment: @meagar I started out with the way you suggested, but don't quite remember why I had to abandon it. I think I hit roadblock when I need to return an AJAX object for a AJAX call from client. I don't know how to add an additional attribute to it.

Comment: @Deradon You'd make a second class to house a single 5 line method? That's a terrible idea, especially in this case, where the method is explicitly meant to behave like a read-only attribute of an Exam. Don't do that. You're not keeping anything "clean" by introducing a million silly 5 line classes.

Comment: @meagar It depends. If I use this rating frequently in my application, like comparing, sorting, some math and so on, yes I'd to this. The rating-logic does not belong to the Exam-class.

Comment: @Deradon Preemptively doing so doesn't make any sense. You can't go creating new classes instead of adding methods to existing classes in every situation where you *might* someday want to add complexity.